# How to exclude one category from echoing

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using the following code to echo the name of the category of the post:

```
<a href=""> <?php $category = get_the_category();  echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?> </a>
```

However, there is one category name that I need to exclude from being echoed. How can I exclude one particular category name from echoing in this code?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to "exclude" one category? Or stop "echoing"? To stop echoing, just remove echo o.O

Comment: It works fine but only there is one category that I don't want to include. In other words 'don't echo if that one category is for the post', does that make sense? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ternary operator:

```
echo ($category[0]->cat_nam == 'excluded_category' ? '' : $category[0]->cat_name) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use wp_list_categories().

Or, do a foreach get_the_category() and a conditional to check your category (don't recommend).

```
$categories = wp_list_categories('echo=0&show_count=0&style=none&hide_empty=1');
```